# Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha - Long data series

Tags: curated-data, finance, wolfram-alpha-queries

Let's say I want a long series of data with the Mexican peso / US dollar exchange rate. The old code I used back in the day was

```
FinancialData["USD/MXN", All]
```

Which produces

> ```
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

If I do a nice compact WolframAlpha query from my Mathematica notebook such as

```
=USD/MXN
```

I get the full history which in the Pod graph can be extended up to ten years.

So far so good. I want to turn this into computable data, so I right-click the graph in the Pod, select Paste Input For > Computable Data, and Mathematica gives me

```
WolframAlpha["USD/MXN", {{"History", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

Which will give me a full year of MXN/USD quotes.

If I change the Pod to give me 5 or 10 years, I will see the data in the graph. However, if I want to convert that to computable data, the only thing I will get is the same

```
WolframAlpha["USD/MXN", {{"History", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
```

which again, will give me a full year only.

How can I get the 10 year series? Do I need to pay for that data or get an API token? That is beyond my skills, but would love to learn.